# ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I need some help with this issue. Sunddenly I'm getting this error. I did no modifications and can't find a solution... here goes a piece of the error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the
>   attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean
>   attachToRoot)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6687)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
>                   at com.beloo.widget.chipslayoutmanager.ChipsLayoutManager.layoutDisappearingViews(ChipsLayoutManager.java:767)
>                   at com.beloo.widget.chipslayoutmanager.ChipsLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(ChipsLayoutManager.java:731)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
>                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)

```
    package com.example.xandi.amicer;

    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            SectionPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

            TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

            mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
            tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tab_home, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

> Here is the class I suppose that is causing this error

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
 @Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, true);
}
```

Comment: it just gimme another error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."